# Pyramid of numbers using (for) Java

Tags: java, for-loop

[image: I am trying to do this as an output...]

a pyramid of numbers thats core is increasing by one which would be seen horizontally as 12345.

I figured out this code 
but its not as the img I shown up there ^

the code I wrote is:

```
int rowCount = 1;
for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i*2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++)             
        {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        } 

        for (int j = rowCount-1; j >= 1; j--)
        {                 
            System.out.print(j+" ");             
        }                          

        System.out.println();

        rowCount++;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Hard to keep up with all those new features of JavaScript

Comment: couple of things: why are you using `System.out.print(j+" "); `?I don't see spaces between the numbers. secondly, which part do you think isn't working? have you tried debugging the code or just simply getting a sheet of paper and going line by line through the code?